# How can I send an email through my Exchange ActiveSync mail account?

Tags: android

How can I send an email through my Exchange ActiveSync mail account and not gmail? When I use createchooser only gmail appears...

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    String aEmailList[] = { "me@mail.com" };
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);   
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: Is your Activesync account setup?

Comment: Sure, I can send emails trough ActiveSync...

Comment: Can you post your code of intent here?

Comment: Looks alright, it should have brought the exchange under the purview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

works for me! :-)